# Find similarity score between several groups based on their key values

Tags: python, dataframe

I have data with 1000 groups. I want to compare each group with 999 other groups and if the value matches, then count as 1 else

the similarity score between g1 and g2 is
6/9 = 66.67%

I am looking for a python solution that provides a matrix (1000*1000) with similarity score

data sample for two groups (of thousand groups) -

```
group, key1, key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, value
g1, kg11, kg12, kg13, kg14, kg15, kg16, [0.1]
g1, kg111, kg112, kg113, kg114, kg115, kg116, [xyz]
g1, kg1111, kg1112, kg1113, kg1114, kg1115, kg1116, None
g1, kg11111, kg11112, kg11113, kg11114, kg11115, kg11116, [false]
g1, kg111111, kg111112, kg111113, kg111114, kg111115, kg111116, [1123, 2314,5678]
g1, kg1111111, kg1111112, kg1111113, kg1111114, kg1111115, kg1111116, [1, 5]
g2, kg11, kg12, kg13, kg14, kg15, kg16, [0.2]
g2, kg111, kg112, kg113, kg114, kg115, kg116, [xyz]
g2, kg1111, kg1112, kg1113, kg1114, kg1115, kg1116, None
g2, kg11111, kg11112, kg11113, kg11114, kg11115, kg11116, [true]
g2, kg111111, kg111112, kg111113, kg111114, kg111115, kg111116, [1123, 2314,5678]
g2, kg1111111, kg1111112, kg1111113, kg1111114, kg1111115, kg1111116, [1, 7]
```

Value matches means -
`g1, kg111, kg112, kg113, kg114, kg115, kg116, [xyz] MATCHES WITH g2, kg111, kg112, kg113, kg114, kg115, kg116, [xyz]`

Why is score in your example equals to 6/9?

Total values - 9 Matches Values - 6

Comment: What does "value matches" mean exactly? Why is score in your example equals to 6/9?

Comment: Value matches meaning - 
g1, kg111, kg112, kg113, kg114, kg115, kg116, [xyz] 
MATCHES WITH
g2, kg111, kg112, kg113, kg114, kg115, kg116, [xyz]

Comment: Does 'value matches' mean that they have identical items in  key1-key6 and value columns?

Comment: Why is score in your example equals to 6/9?

g1, kg11, kg12, kg13, kg14, kg15, kg16, [0.1] - NO MATCH (count - 0)
g1, kg111, kg112, kg113, kg114, kg115, kg116, [xyz] - MATCH (count - 1)
g1, kg1111, kg1112, kg1113, kg1114, kg1115, kg1116, None - MATCH (count - 1)
g1, kg11111, kg11112, kg11113, kg11114, kg11115, kg11116, [false] - NO MATCH (count 0)
g1, kg111111, kg111112, kg111113, kg111114, kg111115, kg111116, [1123, 2314,5678] - MATCH (count 3)
g1, kg1111111, kg1111112, kg1111113, kg1111114, kg1111115, kg1111116, [1, 5]
- PARTIAL MATCH (count 1)
Total values - 9
Matches Values - 6

Comment: Does 'value matches' mean that they have identical items in key1-key6 and value columns? - YES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

The idea is to create a unique key from all the columns and use that a single comparison key. Then iterate over the group pairs and count the total possible records and the number of records that match.

1. Create the unique key

```
match_cols = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5', 'key6', 'value']
df['keyid'] = df.apply(lambda x: '_'.join([str(x[col]) for col in match_cols]), axis=1)
df = df[['group','keyid']].copy()

#   group   keyid
# 0 g1      kg11_ kg12_ kg13_ kg14_ kg15_ kg16_ [0.1]
# 1 g1      kg111_ kg112_ kg113_ kg114_ kg115_ kg116_ [xyz]
# 2 g1      kg1111_ kg1112_ kg1113_ kg1114_ kg1115_ kg111...
```

2. Iterate over group pairs and perform the counting to calculate percentage.

```
results = []

# Iterate over each group to start comparison with
for group_a in range(1, 3):
    
    # Get group data to compare with
    mask = df['group']==f"g{group_a}"
    df_a = df[mask].copy()
    
    # Iterate over each group to compare with
    for group_b in range(1, 3):
        
        # Get group data for comparison
        mask = df['group']==f"g{group_b}"
        df_b = df[mask].copy()  
        
        # Get combination of all records
        df_all = df_a.merge(df_b, how='outer', on='keyid')
        total_records = df_all.shape[0]
        
        # Remove any records that do not match
        total_matches = df_all.dropna(how='any').shape[0]

        # Retain results
        results.append([group_a, group_b, total_matches, total_records, round(total_matches / total_records, 2)])

df_results = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['group_a', 'group_b', 'total_records', 'total_matches','match %'])
df_results


#         group_a   group_b    total_records    total_matches   match %
# 0        1        1          6                6               1.00
# 1        1        2          6                9               0.67
# 2        2        1          6                9               0.67
# 3        2        2          6                6               1.00
```

**Note**:

To optimize, don't compare identical groups and don't compare the same groups twice.

Comment: how do you get df_common?

Comment: I edited the code. My mistake, I renamed the dataframes for readability but missed that. It just df_all.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. one q - will this work when there is a keyid in g1 but not in g2?
because when that happens, then group_a = 1 and group_b=1  does not have a match % of 100%

Comment: It will, yes. I don't understand your second question. group_a = 1 means "g1" and group_b=1 mean "g1", so they are the same group they will always have 100% matching. Is that correct?